# Issue with SceneKit/ModelIO position

Tags: scenekit

I am using ModelIO to voxelise a SceneKit node, here is what I am doing:
[image]

Unfortunately the voxels nodes don't appear in the scene at the same place than the node used to generate those (for instance if I want to voxelise a sphere placed at (0, 2, 0) the vowelised contents appear out of the center of my scene, I thought that there may be an issue between SceneKit and ModelIO coordinate systems (for instance that SceneKit would have y up whereas ModelIO would have z up) but no matter the base coordinates of the sphere (2, 0, 0) (0, 2, 0) or (0, 0, 2) the voxels never appear centered.

So you see an issue in my code ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have the actual source code next time instead of a screenshot?

It looks like you don't do anything with input `node`'s position. You never assign a position to `base`, so its position in the scene is (0, 0, 0). All of the voxels are placed relative to `base`'s position.

```
base.position = node.position
```

As an aside: instead of adding `base` to the hardwired `gameView.scene?.rootNode` as a side effect, consider returning `base` as a result. I'm also a bit surprised that you're able to move the input `node` from the original scene to `tempScene`.

Comment: I don't really think I need to displace the base as the voxelisation seems to generate the voxels relative to the scene origin.

Comment: Maybe so. Copy/paste your code (not the screenshot) and I'll try it in a Playground tomorrow.